# Need to remove certain bracketed text in Word using macros

Tags: ms-word

I have a word count on each page of a document in parentheses and want to remove all instances of it. I have other words in parentheses that I do not want to remove.

For example, on each page at the bottom, you will see (230 words) or (346 words) and I cant find a macro to remove only parentheses text that includes the string "words" and not other strings with parenthesis such as (Today) or (Tomorrow).

This works well to remove all text inside any parentheses, but I want to exclude anything in parentheses that does not include "words". What am I missing?

```
Sub Test_Replace()
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = "\(*\)"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a macro for this, all you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = \([0-9]@ words\)
Replace = nothing
```

Comment: That worked great. Couldn't figure out the proper syntax. Thank you.